# With ASP.NET MVC, how can users POST a model dependent on what was selected in a SelectList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my application, I have a desired flow to create an object.

Just for demonstration, I will say my object is a "Pokemon". So I have an interface for "Pokemon" with stats that are relevant to all of them, something like:

```
public interface IPokemon
{
        string Type { get; set; }
        public static List<SelectListItem> TypeList { get; }
        int HPStat { get; set; }
        int ATKStat { get; set; }
        int DEFStat { get; set; }
        int SPATKStat { get; set; }
        int SPDEFStat { get; set; }
}
```

I then have an abstract `Pokemon` class:

```
public abstract class Pokemon : IPokemon
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> TypeList { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
    {   new SelectListItem { Value = "Bulbasaur", Text = "Bulbasaur" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Squirtle", Text = "Squirtle" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Charmander", Text = "Charmander" }
    };
    // also implements each of the int Stats
}
```

In the HTML, I bind the select to the `TypeList`, for the string `Type` on the IPokemon interface. The object passed from the server is a `Bulbasaur` by default.

```
<select asp-for="Type" asp-items="IPokemon.TypeList"></select>
```

When I try to POST the result, there is an error because an `IPokemon` cannot be initialized.

I understand why the error occurs, but I'm having trouble figuring out what is the best way to structure this interaction as a whole. I assumed I want to return a different model object depending on which the user selects, but I'm also thinking I might have a wrong interpretation of how this should be structured in general.

After this step, I figured I would create the correct model Object depending on what was returned, and then continue in the creation process by allowing certain options dependent on which `Pokemon` class was chosen in this first step. An example; if Squirtle were chosen on this step I'd want to move to a page that allows selection of different "water type" moves.

Any clarification or pointing to resources to learn how to achieve this is welcome.

Comment: What is model class for your view? Can you show the whole view, not just one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few pointers:

Firstly, I wonder if you actually wanted to make your `Pokemon.TypeList` static?
At the moment, the way you have it means that every object of type `Pokemon` (or any of its sub-classes) will have a list of all of the `Pokemon` types. This seems like a lot of data duplication.

Secondly, in your combo box you have `asp-items="IPokemon.TypeList"` but the `TypeList` object is currently sitting in the `Pokemon` class, and not in the `IPokemon` interface.
I expect this is a typo and that you're actually wanting to point to `Pokemon.TypeList`.
Furthermore, you wouldn't really have a list of types sitting withiin an interface anyway really. They'd be better sitting in the base class or even just off in their own static class somewhere else.

Thirdly, regards structure: If all of your `Pokemon` objects are inheriting from your abstract base class, it would seem to me to make more sense to have all of your abstract `IPokemon` methods sitting in your base class, as adding an extra interface only really adds complexity here.

I remember reading one thing in terms of stuff like inheritance and interfaces that's stuck with me: When inheritance trees are taught in an academic context, it's done with the premise that you're going to have a very hierarchical inheritance structure (e.g. classes A and B inherit from class C , class C and D inherit from class E) whereas in the real world your inheritance structures tend to be very flat (as in, classes A, B, C, and D all inherit from class E) Things are just a lot simpler to do this way.

Hope these pointers make sense to you! If not, hit me up with a question

Comment: It's a good point that the interface isn't really doing anything for me. Thank you for that advice. The list *is* intended to be static and I edited the question to reflect that. The base class will still be abstract, so does this mean I should extend it to a class specifically for this view? Would it be too "hacky" to use a `Bulbasaur.TypeList`?

Comment: The thing here is that an abstract class can have static members, such as List<object>, so a list like yours could sit in your base class fine :-)
However, I might want my abstract class to have a List<string> for the types, and then my view or somewhere else convert that to a List<SelectListItem>, as your model shouldn't care about view logic